# What is config.properties in Spring and what is the use of it

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a simple CRUD operation on task management.

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SampleApplication</display-name>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>html/homepage.html</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

</web-app>
```

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties"/>

    <!-- Spring will search in the bellow paths controller an services annotations-->   
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.itc" /> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/html/**" location="/html/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/task" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Im getting the below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:142)
    ... 16 more
```

What does config.properties file missing mean? Im new to spring and trying to configure Spring MVC.

Comment: the config.properties file is to configure the application without changing the code. It has nothing to do with spring. Such as dbconnection string, username, Password  and so on

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Comment: @Jens Then Why Im getting FileNotFoundexception? I tried with creating the properties file and mention it in the spring-servlet file. But getting the same error.

Comment: It must be in the classpath of the application

Answer (score 1):

You have defined

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties"/>
```

That is, you want the application to load properties from the file `config.properties` found in the application's classpath.

The error means that it cannot find this file.

Without knowing your exact layout, build-chain or how you start the application I can't say exactly where you should put this file in order to have it available to the application. Somewhere like `/src/main/resources/` perhaps.

If instead you don't need this file or externalised properties in general, you can stop telling the application that you do: Remove its definition from `spring-servlet.xml`.

Comment: I dont need that config.properties file and I removed it too. But im getting the same exception.

Comment: Go the other way and give it an empty file to load then.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have properties file in your application, remove this line from the Spring-servlet.xml file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties"/>
```

You are telling spring to search for a properties file named *config.properties* which does not exists.

If you need a properties file, then create the *config.properties* and put it in your classpath.

Comment: I removed it from Spring-servlet.xml file still Im getting the same exception

Comment: Are you sure? i copied your xml files in my workspace and adding the *context:property* line i get the error, but when i remove, it works as expected. Have you restarted the server? clean and build the project?

Answer (score 1):

config.properties used to save application variables (properties). I find it very useful because:

- This file as mentioned can store some initial application cofig data,
  like db connection.
- You can create your own properties and inject their values within Spring application. Also this properties can be preset with application run command (command line arguments)
- You can compile your application with config.properties inside, but on deployment create config.properties outside of compiled app and Spring will use properties from it instead of compiled file.
- You can preset profiles, and they will help on development, test, and deployment stage, because each bean can be marked with profile and will be injected depending on your application run mode.

These are features I use, and could be much more. Actually I not find any description how-to about config.properties. All this stuff mentioned in different places in Spring manual.

**Update**

Try Spring Boot - it contains Spring MVC, Hibernate and I found many good examples for starters. It was build to reduce initial config efforts.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you have config.properties and the file is placed in the /WEB-INF/classes folder and use classpath:/config.properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use properties file you will have to declare bean org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your Spring-servlet.xml file.

**Your Spring-servlet.xml:**

```
<bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

your datasource bean will look like the following.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="db.url.property" />
    <property name="username" value="db.user" />
    <property name="password" value="db.password" />
</bean>
```

You should have config.properties in your class path containing following properties.

**Your config.properties**

```
 db.url.property=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/task
 db.user=root
 db.password=root
```

Comment: Where shall I place that config.properties file?

Comment: I always used to follow the convention in my java project to have two source folders "src/main/java" (containing all java files) and "src/main/resources" (contains all resource files like config.properties). You can check the source code of the mkyong example mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-examp‌​le.